# how do I change value in specific columns that with specific Id?

Tags: python, pandas

```
 Id  Predicted_x  Predicted_y
0               10003_age    57.889686    57.355839
1      10003_domain1_var1    50.882433    49.880699
2      10003_domain1_var2    58.253825    59.887124
3      10003_domain2_var1    49.924002    50.361772
4      10003_domain2_var2    54.770036    55.455363
...                   ...          ...          ...
29380           21753_age    41.117583    42.791951
29381  21753_domain1_var1    46.620846    43.665928
29382  21753_domain1_var2    60.091322    59.646989
29383  21753_domain2_var1    46.042158    45.920220
29384  21753_domain2_var2    52.290454    53.746459
```

I am stuck in finding the row with specific Id such as 10003_age and 21753_age, and change the predicted_x of that row

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here:

```
df['Predicted_x'] = np.where(df['Id']=='10003_age', 100, df['Predicted_x'])
print(df)

                   Id  Predicted_x  Predicted_y
0           10003_age   100.000000    57.355839
1  10003_domain1_var1    50.882433    49.880699
2  10003_domain1_var2    58.253825    59.887124
3  10003_domain2_var1    49.924002    50.361772
4  10003_domain2_var2    54.770036    55.455363
5           21753_age    41.117583    42.791951
6  21753_domain1_var1    46.620846    43.665928
7  21753_domain1_var2    60.091322    59.646989
8  21753_domain2_var1    46.042158    45.920220
9  21753_domain2_var2    52.290454    53.746459
```

Or you can use [df.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) as well, first get the index of the row to be changed then use `df.at`:

```
index = df.loc[df['Id']=='10003_age'].index
df.at[index, 'Predicted_x'] = 100
print(df)

                   Id  Predicted_x  Predicted_y
0           10003_age   100.000000    57.355839
1  10003_domain1_var1    50.882433    49.880699
2  10003_domain1_var2    58.253825    59.887124
3  10003_domain2_var1    49.924002    50.361772
4  10003_domain2_var2    54.770036    55.455363
5           21753_age    41.117583    42.791951
6  21753_domain1_var1    46.620846    43.665928
7  21753_domain1_var2    60.091322    59.646989
8  21753_domain2_var1    46.042158    45.920220
9  21753_domain2_var2    52.290454    53.746459
```